# google calendar api watch java script

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am currently working with google calendar api and trying to write a function in javascript that uses the `calendar.events.watch` function in order to be updated if there is an update in the user's calendar *(cancellation, creation or modification).*

I am trying to see what information I get in order to understand if this service is relevant for my needs - knowing if a change happened or even -what- change has happend.

I'm opening a channel and provide the data, but when I make changes to my calendar I don't get any response as detailed here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch

This is The Function I wrote:

```
function watchEvents(token) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  var oauth2ClientPromise = createAuthObject(token);
  console.log('step 1')
  return oauth2ClientPromise
  .then(function (authObject){
    console.log('step 3')
    return Q.nfcall(calendar.events.watch, {
      auth: authObject,
      calendarId: '*I put here my email*',
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
      resource:{
        id: channel_id,
        token: 'email=' + '* placed my email*',
        type: 'web_hook',
        address: '*placed my address*',
        params: {
          ttl: '36000'
        }
      }

    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
console.log('step 2');
  });
}
```

I ran the code:

```
    calendar.watchEvents(token_parsed).then((result)=>console.log("result"))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

I got no errors, and it typed my 'step 1' and 'step 3' flags, but when I changed events in the calendar I did not get any notifications.

This is what I got in the console:

step 1
Example app listening on port 8080!
step 3
result

Does anyone know here what kind of information I am supposed to get from the API? How Does it Look? And wht did mine not work?

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I edited your question, adding the code you made in a comment, you see, comments are not for add code. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: the page you linked to tells you what the response should look like, there's an example in the "Response" section of the page...

Comment: ...in the meantime it appears you sent the API a field called start_time that it wasn't expecting. Again, check the "Request" section of the link to see what parameters are valid.

Answer (score 3):

**but when I changed events in the calendar I did not get any
notifications**

[Making watch requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests) is enabled by sending a POST request to the watch method for the resource as stated in the guide.

Also note that:

> "Each notification channel is associated both with a particular user
>   and a particular resource (or set of resources). A watch request will
>   not be successful unless the current user owns or has permission to
>   access this resource."

Example

Start watching for changes to a collection of events on a given calendar:

```
    POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
    Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
    Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://sampledomain.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
  }
}
```

You can read more of that from the official guide including the [Receiving Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications) tuts.

Comment: where can I find a list of `type`s I wasn't able to find it on the documentations :(

Comment: @noogui When I create a new calendarId and add an event, the channel does not notify me back.. Do you know why this happens? (In primary calendarId it works pretty well)